# Hi, I made an expressjs app to play video files in browser but video seeking is not working on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, express, html5-video

So i made this app so i can play videos from my pc on my phone and i made it start the video from when i closed it. It's working fine on chrome (pc) but on my phone (iOS 16) it starts from the beginning and the seek bar is not even working

````
  fetch("/progress", { keepalive: false })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
          for (var x = 0; x < playlist.length; x++) {
              if (playlist[x].name === json.now_playing) {
                  vidNow = x;
                  vidPlay(vidNow, true);
                  video.currentTime = json.current_duration
                  vSeek.value = json.current_duration
              }
          }
          if (vidNow == 0) vidPlay(0, true);
      }); 

 var vidStart = true,
      vidPlay = (idx, nostart) => {
          vidNow = idx;
          vidStart = nostart ? false : true;
          video.src = encodeURI(playlist[idx]["src"]);
          for (let i in playlist) {
              if (i == idx) {
                  playlist[i]["row"].classList.add("now");
              } else {
                  playlist[i]["row"].classList.remove("now");
              }
          }
      };```
````

Comment: Since the playing of the video appears to occur in the function `vidPlay()`, that's likely the code we need to see.  Probably the headers aren't being set up correct to indicate where the playing should start.

Comment: @jfriend00 edited it in,  i'm using `video.currentTime` to indicate when it should start

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as per the help pages here.  There's just not enough context here to fully understand what you're trying to do or where the play start time comes from as we don't know what many of these variables are or where they come from.  You should be able to use a snippet in your question to show an actual demonstration of the problem.

Comment: ive uploaded the entire project here https://github.com/alexdominat/videoplayer

Comment: @AlexKotrotsios I would put an `alert("vidNow is: " + vidNow");` before the `if (vidNow == 0) vidPlay(0, true);` code to make sure that nothing is causing the `vidPlay` to start at **0** time.